# Email from "Drafts" being delivered blank

Tags: windows, email, exchange, exchange-2010, outlook

We're having several problems when users send email from the "Drafts" in Outlook 2010.

For example: when an email is saved in the `Drafts` folder one day and sent on another day, the delivered email has a blank body. When they look in `Sent Items`, the message is blank there as well. This seems to happen randomly.  There are no errors generated.

I can see in the message tracking logs that the email was delivered successfully. It has a size of 12 KB, which means that email is not really empty. However, there is no text in body of email (email in sent items is empty, email in recipient inbox is empty). Microsoft Forefront Protection has not performed any actions in this time frame to explain this behavior. Does anyone have any ideas on what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I would start with mailbox repair command, on the affected mailboxes:

```
New-MailboxRepairRequest -Mailbox "mailboxname" -CorruptionType ProvisionedFolder,SearchFolder,AggregateCounts,Folderview
```

Watch the logs to see if any corruptions have been fixed. The repair can be run while user is connected.

Comment: thank you for tip. I did it, but no problem was found. I checked also the event logs. Do you have any other suggestion? Thank you in advance

Comment: What mode are your users are working at? Online? Offline?

Comment: hi, sorry for delay. All of them have online mode.

Comment: Have you applied SP2 to Exchange and all the patches from windows update to the Outlook(office) on user's computer? Is that happens to one particular users or several?

Comment: we have SP2 RU3... yes, everything is up to date.
Several users are affected, but it occurs only rarely

Comment: Do you see any issues in the application event log on the server?

Comment: there is no error in the application log in that time. I checked both servers (mailbox and CAS+HUB)

Comment: Is there a chance to compare the outlook.exe version on the affected workstations, with the ones which are not experiencing issues?

Comment: Outlook is installed on terminal server. All users use the same version. On the other hand, I don't think that all users saved their emails to drafts. Anyway this problem occurs only rarely. I am not able to simulate this situation. That's a reason, why I am so frustrated.